# c# "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Tags: arrays, indexing

Trying to solve this problem I am having with using array information in my request.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
public int[] custid = new int[] {};

_request2.CustID = custid[_response.Customers[3].CustID];
```

Now after debugging the program and walking through each part of the above line, everything is correct, but when I try and run the program it gives me the error "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You allocated an empty array. Then you tried to access an element of your empty array.

You need to have elements in the array like:

```
public int[] custid = new int[10];
```

or

```
public int[] custid = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

If you are looking for something more flexible (like being able to add and remove elements), I suggest a list.

Comment: I think my problem is coming from when I have to use elements that come from my response. The values (customer IDs) are generated once the request is sent but when I try to put those values from the request I get the error that I Index was outside the bounds of the array. Even after I changed it to this ' int[] custid = new int[_response.Customers[12].CustID];'